# How to make child pages inherit a parent bundle

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I would like to know how I could make child pages (more than 10k) inherit a parent page plugin.

The old way to make a plugin, was to create a `pi1/class.tx_extkey_pi1.php` file that extends `\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Plugin\AbstractPlugin`
and that it was easy to set in parent page and automatically the children pages.

Now, with an Extbase MVC plugin, I've got controllers than extend `ActionController` but I can't make it recursive.

Does somebody know a way to do it?

Big thank you for any help

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to say hello before asking my question
so ... hi everybody!

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the `uid` values of the nested child pages, or do you want to inherit the execution of the plugin to sub-pages (basically by using TypoScript). Maybe you could provide some code of your previous `AbstractPlugin` based class

Comment: Yes i could provide the code of the previous version but it's not in the code the problem. It's the way to do the thinks. Before, when adding the plugin to the template of a page, the children pages were also affected. Now when i do it, i just can manipulate the configuration on children pages but to use actions i need to add the plugin in a content block

Comment: Ah, it's only about TypoScript and how to call Extbase classes? In old versions you used `userFunc = tx_extkey_pi1->main` and you'd like to know how this is done with Extbase, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### AbstractPlugin

Classes that inherit from `AbstractPlugin` (so called Pi-Based-Plugins) where invoked in TypoScript like this:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = USER
page.10 {
  userFunc = tx_myext_pi1->main
}
```

### Extbase

Using the Extbase MVC dispatcher, plugins are called like the following - this will call the first registered action of the first registered controller in `ext_localconf.php`:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = USER
page.10 {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    vendorName = MyVendor
    extensionName = MyExtension
    pluginName = MyPlugin
}
```

However, there's a work-around to select a specific action in TypoScript using `switchableControllerActions` - the follow TypoScript invokes `MyVendor\MyExtension\MyController::myAction()`:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = USER
page.10 {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    vendorName = MyVendor
    extensionName = MyExtension
    pluginName = MyPlugin
    switchableControllerActions {
        My {       // automatically expanded to class name "MyController"
            0 = my // automatically expanded to method name "myAction"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Oliver Hader for taking your time, i'll test it. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, i tested it and it works, the children of the page herited the plugin.

The only think is that it doesn't extends the main layout